# Rails activemodel & actionmailer contact me form returns no route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actionmailer, activemodel

I'm trying to create a 'contact me' form with activemodel to avoid generating needless tables. When I submit the contact form, rails returns the error `No route matches [POST] "/contact/new"`, despite the following routes

## config/routes.rb

```
resources :contact, only: [:new, :create]
```

`rake routes` returns the following...

```
   contact_index POST   /contact(.:format)                     contact#create
   new_contact GET    /contact/new(.:format)                 contact#new
```

## controller/contact_controller.rb

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    if @contact.valid?
      ContactMailer.contact_submit(@contact).deliver
      flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your email, I'll respond shortly"
      redirect_to new_contact_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

## mailers/contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: ENV[EMAIL_ADDRESS]

  def contact_submit(msg)
    @msg = msg
    mail(from: @msg.email, name: @msg.name, message: @msg.message)
  end
end
```

## models/contact.rb

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  validates_presence_of :message
  validates_presence_of :name

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

## views/contact/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @contact, url: new_contact_path do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %><br>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :message %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :message %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring resources you should use the plural form:

```
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
```

This goes with the RESTful idea that you are operating on a collection of resources.

Your form should post to `contacts_path` not `new_contacts_path`. The `new` and `edit` actions respond to GET and just render forms in rails.

In fact you can just pass the record to `form_for` and use convention over configuration:

```
<%= form_for(@contact) %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

This will automatically route to to `contacts_path`. You seldom need to manually set the URL for a form in rails.

Comment: If you really want to have a singular resource use the `resource` macro instead. It generates the correct route names.

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting the form to `new_contact_path`(`/contact/new`) whose method is `GET` and not `POST`. By default, `form_for` constructs a form with `method` set to `post`.

So, when you submit, rails is looking for `new_contact_path` with `POST` verb which doesn't exist and so, no route matches.

Remove the `url` option from `form_for`.

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
  # form elements
<% end %>
```

Rails will take care of the url to submit, the form will be submitted to `contacts_path`(`/contacts`)

For the above code to work, your route definition should look like the following:

```
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
```